# AutoHotKey script stopped working

Tags: autohotkey

I have been using the following script for a while so that I can write in Portuguese.

For example:

- **Ctrl+Shift+~ followed by e** is supposed to output '€'
- **Ctrl+Alt+a** is supposed to output 'á'

The script worked fine on my PC for ages. It works fine on my laptop. Both are running the same version of AHK (1.1.09.04), both are 64-bit machines running AHK in 32-bit mode.

But suddenly it's stopped working on my PC.

- **Ctrl+Shift+~ followed by e** gives me '4'
- **Ctrl+Alt+a** outputs just 'a'

This is the script I have been using. What would cause it to stop working on my PC? I've tried uninstalling and re-installing to no avail.

```
^~::
  Input Combo, L1
  If Combo=a
    Send ã
  If Combo=o
    Send õ
  If Combo=e
    Send €
  If Combo=0
    Send °
  Return

^+6::
  Input Combo, L1
  If Combo=a
    Send â
  If Combo=e
    Send ê
  If Combo=o
    Send ô
  Return

^!a::á
^!e::é
^!i::í
^!o::ó
^!u::ú
^!c::ç

^!+a::Á
^!+e::É
^!+i::Í
^!+o::Ó
^!+u::Ú
^!+c::Ç

^`::
  Input Combo, L1
  If Combo=a
    Send à
  Return

^+`::
  Input Combo, L1
  If Combo=a
    Send À
  Return
```

Comment: Can someone add a more descriptive title than "AutoHotKey script stopped working"?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro was it necessary to downvote!?

Comment: Feel free to suggest a more descriptive title... I can't think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hainesy, could it be that you have recently changed the keyboard settings from e.g. `US` to `US International`?

The US keyboard behaves very straight forward whereas the US International keyboard settings will "withhold" special characters like <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> and the escape character on the <kbd>~</kbd> key and wait for the next character. If the next character is a <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd>, it will combine the two single characters into letters like <kbd>è</kbd><kbd>á</kbd><kbd>ü</kbd><kbd>î</kbd><kbd>ç</kbd>.

Your script could be messed up because the initiating character <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> and the escape below the <kbd>~</kbd> is not behaving straight forward anymore.

Comment: I don't think it was this. After a machine reboot today it all seems to be working ok though...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I should have thought about a reboot as well, but forgot.